# Router provider doesn't receive children causing wrapping problem at test

Tags: reactjs, testing

Have this problem

--> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a

I looked for other solutions and they are wrapping the main component App.tsx in the , but in React Router 6 it doesn't receive a children Prop.

This is my Main.tsx app

```
 <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
```

And the test

```
describe('Home', () => {
 it('should render', () => {
    render(
        <StaticRouter location={{}}>
            <Home />
        </StaticRouter>
    )
 })
})
```